# Pandas DataFrame sort ignoring the case

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe in Python. The contents of the dataframe are from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Singles_Chart_records_and_statistics#Most_weeks_at_number_one). I modified the case of the first alphabet in the "Single" column slightly. Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print df

Position                       Artist                  Single               Year     Weeks
       1                Frankie Laine               I Believe               1953  18 weeks
       2                  Bryan Adams         I Do It for You               1991  16 weeks
       3                  Wet Wet Wet      love Is All Around               1994  15 weeks
       4  Drake (feat. Wizkid & Kyla)               One Dance               2016  15 weeks
       5                        Queen       bohemian Rhapsody  1975/76 & 1991/92  14 weeks
       6                 Slim Whitman              Rose Marie               1955  11 weeks
       7              Whitney Houston  i Will Always Love You               1992  10 weeks
```

I would like to sort by the **Single** column in ascending order (a to z). When I run

```
df.sort_values(by='Single',inplace=True)
```

it seems that the sort is not able to combine upper and lowercase. Here is what I get:

```
Position                       Artist                  Single               Year     Weeks
       1                Frankie Laine               I Believe               1953  18 weeks
       2                  Bryan Adams         I Do It for You               1991  16 weeks
       4  Drake (feat. Wizkid & Kyla)               One Dance               2016  15 weeks
       6                 Slim Whitman              Rose Marie               1955  11 weeks
       5                        Queen       bohemian Rhapsody  1975/76 & 1991/92  14 weeks
       7              Whitney Houston  i Will Always Love You               1992  10 weeks
       3                  Wet Wet Wet      love Is All Around               1994  15 weeks
```

So, it is sorting by uppercase first and then performing a separate sort by lower case. I want a combined sort, regardless of the case of the starting alphabet in the **Single** column. The row with "bohemian Rhapsody" is in the wrong location after sorting. It should be first; instead it is appearing as the 5th row after the sort.

Is there a way to do sort a Pandas DataFrame while ignoring the case of the text in the **Single** column?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can convert all strings to upper/lower case and then call `argsort()` which gives the index value to reorder the data frame by *Single* ignoring the case:

```
df.iloc[df.Single.str.lower().argsort()]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. Just what i wanted.

Comment: This other answer about using the `key` argument is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141564/543738

Answer (score 40):

Pandas 1.1.0 [introduced the `key` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys) as a more intuitive way to achieve this:

```py
df.sort_values(by='Single', inplace=True, key=lambda col: col.str.lower())
```

Comment:  Best answer.

Comment: @edesz I don't know if you can change the selected best answer but this should be it now.

Answer (score 6):

Create a copy of `Single` in all upper case letters and sort by that column:

```
df["Single.Upper"] = df["Single"].str.upper()
df.sort_values(by="Single.Upper", inplace=True)
```

You can delete the column later:

```
del df["Single.Upper"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing this but didn't want to create a new column. I had unsuccessfully tried using `by=df["Single"].str.upper()`. Is there a way to do this without creating and deleting the extra column?

Comment: Yes. See Psidom's answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, I saw the answer. I was wondering if the option to convert to uppercase (like you did) can be done without creating+deleting the extra column.

Comment: But he is doing just that: converts the column to uppercase and uses it for sorting (actually, for permuting the index).

Comment: Thanks. Missed it earlier. Ok, no further quesions.

Answer (score -1):

make the new column, use it while sorting and delete afterward.

```
df["Single.Lower"] = df["Name"].str.lower()
df.sort_values(['Single.Lower'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
del df["Single.Lower"]
```