# I am trying to sort a csv alphabetically but its not happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, sorting

I am trying to sort a csv file alphabetically by the package column. I am using this code

```
import pandas as pandasForSortingCSV

# assign dataset
csvData = pandasForSortingCSV.read_csv("python_packages.csv")

# displaying unsorted data frame
print("\nBefore sorting:")
print(csvData)

# sort data frame
csvData.sort_values(["package"],
                    axis=0,
                    inplace=True)

# displaying sorted data frame
print("\nAfter sorting:")
print(csvData)
```

These are the results

```
Before sorting:
                      package version                       labels
0                     absl-py   1.2.0  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
1                     aiohttp   3.8.3  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
2                   aiosignal   1.3.1  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
3                     appdirs   1.4.4  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
4    ascalon-audio-data-utils  0.3.37  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
```

```
After sorting:
                 package version                       labels
29                 Flask   2.2.2  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
30      Flask-SQLAlchemy   3.0.2  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
46                Jinja2   3.1.2  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
49   Keras-Preprocessing   1.1.2  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
55              Markdown   3.4.1  ['util-busybox', 'unknown']
```

I don't understand how is it sorting and why I cant get it sort alphabetically

I tried using the sorted as well

```
# import modules
import csv, operator

# load csv file
data = csv.reader(open('python_packages.csv'), delimiter=',')

# sort data on the basis of age
data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

# displaying sorted data
print(data)
```

this is the error I am getting

data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
IndexError: list index out of range

package is the first column

this is befalling me

Comment: what result are you expecting? show us an example

Comment: The end result seems sorted correctly to me, but I suspect the upper case `F` values come first and the lower case `a` values come after that? If so, then you need case-insensitive sorting. See this other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656788/1745616

Comment: Yep the case was messing me up, I spent so much time trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The sorting in python is a little weird. Uppercase letters always become first before lower case letters irregardless of the letter. You can use this to sort it properly:

```
import pandas as pandasForSortingCSV

# assign dataset
csvData = pandasForSortingCSV.read_csv("python_packages.csv")

# displaying unsorted data frame
print("\nBefore sorting:")
print(csvData)

# sort data frame
csvData.sort_values(["package"],
                    axis=0,
                    inplace=True, key=lambda col: col.str.lower())
# displaying sorted data frame
print("\nAfter sorting:")
print(csvData)
```

col.str.lower() converts the name into the lowercase version so the capital letters don't matter.